# Does WebGL 2 support linear depth texture sampling?

Tags: webgl

With WebGL 1 we can use WEBGL_draw_buffers extension which lets us use a texture as the depth attachment on the frame buffer.

And we can chose to use LINEAR or NEAREST as the filtering method.

```
gl.getExtension('WEBGL_draw_buffers');
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height, 0, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, null);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
```

WebGL 2 doesn't require an extension for this, but as soon as I switched to WebGL 2 I noticed that nothing happens unless I use NEAREST as the filtering method.

```
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT24, width, height, 0, gl.DEPTH_COMPONENT, gl.UNSIGNED_INT, null);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR); // wont work
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR); // has to be NEAREST
```

Is there something I have to do to make this possible?

The only workaround for this that I know of would be to draw this depth texture onto another texture, but that seems like a waste of time.

Comment: If linear is not supported then you could read 4 texels and then do bilinear interpolation of the values yourself in the shader ?

Comment: have you tried enabling the extensions `OES_texture_half_float_linear` and `OES_texture_float_linear`?

Comment: @Marvin I have, nothing changed, even after I switched to `DEPTH_COMPONENT32F` it still only works with `NEAREST`. But from your tone it sounds like it should have worked. All examples I managed to find used `NEAREST`, but maybe you know some examples that don't?

Comment: @PaulHK Are you suggesting that 4 reads per fragment would be faster than drawing the depth texture onto another l texture that has a linear filter?

Comment: @zoran404 not really, I just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262432/linear-filtering-of-floating-point-textures-in-webgl2) and thought it was worth a quick check before I looked any further (I've not really worked with textures yet, so this is a learning exercise for me too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf) says depth textures are not filterable.

> #### 3.8.13
>
> ...
>
> Using the preceding definitions, a texture is complete unless any of the following conditions hold true:
>
> - The effective internal format specified for the texture arrays is a sized internal depth or depth and stencil format (see table 3.14), the value of TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE is NONE, and either the magnification filter is not NEAREST or the minification filter is neither NEAREST nor NEAREST_-
>     MIPMAP_NEAREST